# TypeError: can't convert undefined to object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In our project if i place

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Then i am getting the follwing error

> TypeError: can't convert undefined to object in jQuery
>
> set: function( elem, value ) {

Please help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance...

Comment: you need to include jquery.js also

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) depends on [jQuery core](http://jquery.com/) library, so you need to include jquery script before including jquery ui script.

Add the following script before your script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
```